# Remove item from Room database using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my first project on Android.

I have `NotesRecylerAdapter` for `RecyclerView`. On the view of each element I have "delete" button. When clicking on this button I have to remove element from UI and also from database (Room database).

Here is part of the code inside `NotesRecyclerAdapter`. So inside `BindViewHolder` I attach click listener to the delete button. It removed item from Recycler View (from UI), however, it doesn't delete it from database. Can you suggest how to add it also from database? Reference to database is in Activity not in Adapter class. So what mechanism to use?

```
class NotesRecyclerAdapter(private val items: MutableList<Note>) :
     RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesRecyclerAdapter.NoteViewHolder>() {
 ...
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.deleteNote.setOnClickListener {
            items.removeAt(position)

            notifyDataSetChanged()
            //notifyItemRemoved(position)


 // Part of MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val db get() = Database.getInstance(this)
    private val notes = mutableListOf<Note>()

    private lateinit var adapter: NotesRecyclerAdapter
    private lateinit var layoutManager: StaggeredGridLayoutManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        notes.addAll(db.noteDao().getAll())
    ...



 // interface NoteDao
interface NoteDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM note ORDER BY id DESC")
    fun getAll(): List<Note>
   
    @Delete
    fun delete(item: Note)

    ...
}
```

So in MainActivity I load data into "notes". In Adapter I listen on delete button click event. How now to call `db.delete` method?

Comment: can you elaborate more on how you want to delete your item , for example from swipe in recyclerview or clicking an icon or anything else .

Answer (score 1):

In your database define an abstract field for the NoteDao like this:

```
abstract val noteDao: NoteDao
```

then call delete like this:

```
db.noteDao.delete(note)
```

Since this's your first project I suggest reading [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide). It's the recommended architecture for building robust, production-quality apps.